# JQuery UI Hidden Dialog Interferes with Printing

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, printing

I have a calendar that is mostly drawn using SVG. Several aspects of drawing, like language, are controlled by inputs in a JQuery UI dialog. When printing from the browser, I use a media CSS section that hides the dialog and other page components not related to the calendar, so only the calendar prints.

This all works well. Even if the dialog is visible in the browser, the calendar prints as expected, without the dialog showing.

As long as the dialog is centered over the calendar, or shoved to the left. If the dialog is visible and is shoved to the right of the page, even partially, the printed version shrinks dramatically, to roughly half its normal size. Moving the dialog back toward the left restores the printed version to its normal size.

I've tried hiding all ui-* components in the media print CSS wholesale, using both visibility: hidden and display: none, without success. I've poked through the code with the inspector, looking for an oversize div that might be causing this, but I've come up empty.

If the dialog is dismissed, all is well.

This occurs on all browsers I've tried - IE 11, and whatever the most recent versions of Firefox and Chrome are.

Answer (score 0):

After poking around quite a bit, it turns out this is caused by Jquery UI writing style information for some of its components inline. so the 'display: none' in my stylesheet was losing in precedence to the 'display:block' JQUI was forcing into its component. Chaning my stylesheet rule to 'display: none !important' fixed this.

I don't think this is a good design, or solution, but I don't know how else to address it. JQUI should avoid the use of inline styles, and stick to keeping style information in its stylesheet file, as it does with the related 'visibility: hidden' rule it uses for this component when it is not displayed.